# Is it possible to use Identity and OWIN on existing user table having data already?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, owin

I already have  data in a User table which relates to other tables in database.
Is there any solution to use an existing User/Login table from an existing database for implementing identity and OWIN.

I am using asp.net web api and want to apply token based authentication.
I already have a database with important data and a User table with credentials storing in it.

I want to implement Identity functionality on that User table.

Answer (score 0):

This article is exactly what you're looking for:

[Token Based Authentication using ASP.NET Web API 2, Owin, and Identity](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)

Is possible to an existing table as source of truth for user information, and emit OAuth token based on that information.

Hope it helps!